# Encoders on Log4j2

Tags: java, log4j, logback, log4j2

I´m migrating from logback to log4j2 and I´m missing a lot of functionality that exist on logback, but I cannot find a similarity on log4j2

Any idea if there´s a similar feature as **encoder** with   on log4j2?, I cannot find any documentation.

Comment: This is the documentation on [Log4j encoder](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/layout/class-use/Encoder.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think what Logback calls **encoders** are called [Layouts](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html) in Log4j 2.

You may also be interested in [Filters](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html) and [Lookups](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html).

Log4j 2 is being actively maintained. If you have any questions or feature requests, please don't hesitate to contact the Log4j 2 community via the [log4j-user mailing list](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/mail-lists.html) or raise a ticket on the [issue tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2).